# Is it possible to share an arXiv article before it is announced?

Tags: arxiv

Once I submit an article to arXiv, it takes some time to be announced. Is there a way to share the article link before it is announced?  I would like to share it with my friends/guide, so they may point out mistakes, if any, before the article is announced.

Comment: That's what personal websites are for :)

Comment: How about emailing them?

Comment: You mean pdf? No, pdf I've already shared. I was wondering if it is possible to share the link to arXiv page?

Comment: Which information do you want shared?

Comment: The arXiv page: For example, like [this page](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03074). I know the identifier 1910.03074 wouldn't have been generated yet, but there is some other identifier that arXiv has mailed me, where I can view my submission. Is it possible to share link to this so that other authors can view the submission before it is publicly announced?

Comment: I guess you're talking about the email with temporary submission identifier arXiv sends out. I don't know if that identifier/link is tied to your arXiv account, or if it can be shared. But it should be easy to test when you have the link by opening it in a private browser window.

Comment: Yes. Directly it didn't open. I was hoping if it would open with some prefix. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Until the article is announced, it does not have a publicly viewable URL.  It can only be accessed from the account of the submitter.  So you cannot effectively share your paper until it is announced in the regular arXiv mailing.  However, since that announcement should be within *at most* two business days (unless your paper gets flagged for special treatment, because of extensive evidence of plagiarism or some other problem), it should not hurt you too much to wait for the announcement.

Comment: Thanks! Also any idea if I can submit for IEEE journal before my article is publicly viewable on arXiv? Or do I have to wait till it is publicly viewable on arXiv?

Comment: @NagabhushanSN I don't know anything specific about IEEE journals, so I didn't answer your other question.  However, in my experience with other publishers, there is generally no problem with submitted a manuscript that is not on the arXiv.  Some publishers like to know if a manuscript has a arXiv version, but I don't think it is ever mandatory to post a manuscript on the arXiv before submission.  I have, once or twice, been impatient with the arXiv over a long weekend myself and submitted a paper to a journal after submitting it to the arXiv but before it was announced.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just worried about the copyrights (that I can make it publicly available on arXiv, when it is still under review in an IEEE journal)

Answer (score 1):

There is this thing called *email*, which people used to communicate with other people in private, before twitter, Facebook etc. took over. *Email* allows for *attachments*, where one can send files, making it even easier to share work, than to have a link (which might be picked up by google robots and made public).

Moreover, if you really wish to get comments, I suggest to add line-numbering (check out the lineno LaTeX package.) to the preprint, so that one can easily reference parts in the paper. E.g., "on line 123, there is a spellning error" or "on line 456, you should really reference the obscure latin text from 1859 by obscure author".

I have line numbering mandatory for everything my students want to get feedback on.